# Probability of random variables in uniform distribution

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Suppose I have 2 random variables x1 and x2/2. Where both the random variables lie in a uniform distribution between [0, 1].(that means x1 value lies between [0, 1], whereas x2 value lies between [0, 1/2]. What is the probability that when i pick x1 it will be greater than x2? Vice versa.

(My intuition tells mes that its 0.75 chance x1 > x2/2, and 0.25 change x1 < x2/2) But I dont know why that is the case.

Comment: I would draw a rectangle in the first quadrant with a vertex in the origin and line y=x to depict the areas that support your intuition. By symmetry, we see that if both variables have the same range probabilities are 1/2 and 1/2, and as the square turns into a rectangle, more area goes above or below the dividing line, depending on which variable grows or shrinks.

Comment: This image is useful: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiNLK.png, from almost the same question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813947/joint-density-problem-two-uniform-distributions